# SSH connection close after few time

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I create SSH tunnel with multi server with command :

```
ssh -D9999 root@server_5 -J root@server_1,root@server_2,root@server_3,root@server_4
```

SSH connection after few time (sometimes 1 minute ,sometimes 5 minute , sometimes 4 hours , ...) disconnect connection . i want keep SSH connection active . i change ClientAliveInterval and ClientAliveCountMax inside sshd_config to :

```
ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 99999
```

and ServerAliveInterval and ServerAliveCountMax inside ssh_config

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
ServerAliveCountMax 120
```

and also enable "TCPKeepAlive yes" inside sshd_config .
i change all 5 Servers (ssh_config and sshd_config) files and restart SSH serive but also SSH connection closed after time , any advise ?